# Having trouble sending email with nodemailer and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A7DE.png)
[terminal in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpQq6.png)

Here is my code for sendEmail.js:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const sendEmail = async (email, subject, text) => {
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: process.env.HOST,
            service: process.env.SERVICE,
            port: 587,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.USER,
                pass: process.env.PASS,
            },
        });
    await transporter.sendMail({
            from: process.env.USER,
            to: email,
            subject: subject,
            text: text,
        });

        console.log("email sent sucessfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, "email not sent");
    }
};

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

I followed the tutorial at "https://dev.to/cyberwolve/how-to-implement-password-reset-via-email-in-node-js-132m"[Forgot password..](https://dev.to/cyberwolve/how-to-implement-password-reset-via-email-in-node-js-132m)
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The screenshots with the error messages are linked at the top of the screen.

Comment: Do you run a local email server? Or why are you using your loopback address? The error `ECONNREFUSED` is pretty clear.

Comment: I'm using a Gmail email address

Comment: Then again, why are you using the loopback address instead  of the gmail server?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: "127.0.0.1" is your loopback address, and not the gmail server. Why are you using "127.0.0.1" as server/host and not e.g. "smtp.gmail.com"?!

Comment: How do you do that?